# React Native - Is it possible to add more than one RightButton to react native Navigator?

Tags: react-native

I would like to have two buttons on the right side of the navbar. I am using the React Native `Navigator` component. I know I can put a button to the right side of the navbar but how can I put more than one?

[image: Something like this]

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

On Android if you are using `ToolbarAndroid` you can pass an array of items to actions prop.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html#actions

On iOS if you are using `NavigatorIOS` unfortunately there is no way you can do such a thing but if you are using `Navigator` you can design it yourself

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#navigation-bar

Comment: Yes I know about the `Navigator`, I forgot to mention that in my question, Sorry about that. I can only put a button to the right side, I was wondering if I can put more than 1 button.

Comment: Yes it is possible. `Navigator` is made to customize toolbar based on user preferences.
If you pay attention to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#navigation-bar
You see that example sets one `TouchableHighlight`. Why not add a second one beside it?

Comment: Ohh I see, I'll try that thanks! Do you know how I can hide the navigator in certain routes? I've been looking for a way to do it for days but nothing seems to work.